# iPhone keyboard return key

Tags: iphone, keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I need to customize the iphone keyboard. How can I do it? Also it is needed to place the return key of the keyboard with my project logo. How is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot customize the apple iOS's default keyboard.

As such you can create a custom control similar to apple iOS's keyboard and make it look and customize as you want but then there ar more chances than not that your app may be rejected when you try to submit your app on the Apple's app store.

So it is not preferable to create custom keyboard.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey, if I use kviksilver's workaround, would my app be rejected?

Answer (score 2):

What have we done in one of our apps and you can do is create custom uibutton that is same size as return key, then register for  UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification.

when one of those fire you should add/remove that uibutton to window with animation that tracks keyboard showing/hiding animation...

Ugly way to do it, but it served its purpose...

Answer (score 1):

Some of the tutorials are incomplete or are much older. This tutorial works from IOS 4.3 onwards and I checked it. Save the two image graphics, and paste in the code. There is very little to change. Here is the link.

ps. I am not affiliated in any way with this article, but found it to be complete.

http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key